# random variable of pens

Tags: probability, random-variables, combinations

There are 20 pens in a box and 3 of them are without ink.

1.If I pick  3 pens randomly, what’s the probability that all the pens can write.

2.I pick a pen randomly and then I replace it back to the box. I repeat this procedure six times.calculate the probability that we picked at most one pen that with no ink

3.use a Poisson random variable to calculate it again

4.If I pick pens and replace them, how many pens do I have to pick on average until picking up the third pens without ink?

5.Pick out three pens together, and put them back to the basket if not all three are without ink. How many times will you repeat this procedure on average?

I think question one is a hypergeometric distribution

question 2 is a binominal distribution and what should I use in passion random variable since variance is not equal to mean
and I don't know what should I do for the question 4 and 5

Comment: For the first : three from seventeen.

Comment: @AbdallahHammam: Not an answer, possibly a cryptic partial clue?

Answer (score 1):

For 3 use $\lambda=np$, fourth is negative binomial and fifth is geometric, i think.

Comment: Simultaneous with mine (+1).

Answer (score 1):

Here are some answers and clues:

(1) ${17 \choose 3}{3 \choose 0}/{20 \choose 3} \approx 0.60.$
Suggest you compute it to four places. Right $X$ is hypergeometric
and you want $P(X = 3).$

(2) $X$ is the number of pens chosen that have no ink.
$X \sim Binom(6, 3/20).$ Then $P(X \le 1) = P(X=0) + P(X=1) = 0.7765.$

(3) "It" is not perfectly clear. If it means to use a Poisson approximation
to (2), then $Y \sim Pois(\lambda = 18/20)$ and $P(Y\le 1) = 0.7725.$

(4) Negative binomial distribution is correct. Use $p = P(\text{No ink}) = 3/20$ and
you're waiting for $r = 3$ no-ink pens.

(5) "Repeat" in order to get what? Possibly geometric with $1-p$, where $p$ is the answer in (1), and waiting for first draw with some working pens.

Comment: for the question 5 it means how many time I need to do the picking so that I can pick out three pens that without ink

Comment: Thanks. That is what I guessed -- and said in (5) after "Possibly ..." Also, I suppose what @Momo assumed.

Comment: but I was wondering how to classify the question to different kind of  distribution

Comment: The point of the overall question is to provide drill on various kinds of distributions. Part (5) is geometric (a special case of negative binomial).

Comment: sorry that is the fourth question asking for the expected value of negative binomial

Comment: I am still thinking question 5 why p=3/20.since we need to pick out three pens withoug ink together so why it is not 3C3/3C20 =1140